# I'm trying to save question_id and selected answer/answers in the database using nested foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Don't know if my foreach loop is wrong or something else. Either way it's not saving to the databse. 
This is the code for the view where the questions and the options are displayed.

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
<div class="card mt-4" id='questionlist'>
    <div class="card-header" for="question">{{$question->question_order}}{{"."}} {{ $question->question }}</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="list-group" for="answer">
            @foreach($question->options as $option)
            @if(($question->type)=='c')
            <label class="container3">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{$option->option_id}}"> {{ $option->option }}
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            @elseif(($question->type)=='r')
            <label class="container3">
                <input type="radio" name="{{$question->question_id}} " value="{{$option->option_id}}"> {{
                $option->option }}
                <span class="radio"></span>
            </label>
            @endif
            @endforeach
            @if(($question->type)=='s')
            <textarea type="textbox" value="text" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

This is the code from the the controller that saves the questions and options to the database.

```
public function storeAnswers(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->input('question') as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($request->input('answers') as $value => $ans) {
            Answers::save(['question_id' => $value, 'option_id' => $ans]);
        }
    }
    dd('savedshit');
    return redirect('/Dashboard');
}
```

Comment: You did not create `question` and `answer` fields in your form

Comment: How do I get the value of the question_id from the view to the controller?

Comment: Please share your `$questions` query

Comment: $questions = Question::where('questionnaire_id', $request->questionnaire_id)
                        ->where('is_active', '=', 'true')
                        ->orderBy('question_order')->get();

Comment: What is `if(($question->type)=='c'` and `if(($question->type)=='r'.` ? Do you want to get value of  this field only `<input type="radio" name="{{$question->question_id}} " value="{{$option->option_id}}">`?

Comment: c and r are types of options for that particular question. c is for checkbox and r is for radio button. I'm using if statement to display option list as checkbox when the type of option is c and r when it is a radio button. I'm trying to get the value of both checkbox and radiobutton.